# How to read Google OAuth2 UserCredentials from an existing token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api

Instead of obtaining OAuth2 UserCredentials before every Google API interaction, is it instead possible to load the existing token, check the expiry & reuse so as to avoid repetition?

I cannot find a method for loading the existing token from the local file.

Thanks in advance.

```
        public static UserCredential? GetGoogleCredentials(string filename)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error 102 - unable to obtain credentials because {filename} was missing");
                return null;
            }

            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error 108 - unable to obtain credentials because {filename} does not exist");
                return null;
            }

            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                Console.WriteLine("Opening credentials");
                string credPath = ".";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file obtained + saved");
            }
            return credential;
        }
```

Comment: A token has an expiration date.  Initially you get a token and can reuse it until it expires.  The token is usually obtained from the user stores (cookie).  The token is just a string so you can save to a file and then read the file, but the method you store the string a retrieve the string has to be compatible.  In your code you initially do not have a file so Error 102 does not make sense.  Not finding the file just means you never saved the file for the first time.  It is not an error.  When file doesn't exist you need to get the token.

Comment: Hi jdweng. Sure. That's the question: using the above code to save the credentials to a local FileDataStore, what method do you then use to recover those credentials back from there?

Comment: Just read the text file.  Just use File.ReadAllText(filename);